# Why did Steve Bray have his sound system seized?

Tags: england-and-wales, police, freedom-of-speech, protest

What was the legal basis for this? And what is the legal status is amplification systems used for political demonstration in England now?

https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2022/jun/28/police-swoop-on-stop-brexit-man-under-new-anti-protest-law

> Stop Brexit Man: police swoop on Steve Bray and seize sound system
>
> Met officers move against activist on same day that controversial new protest laws come into force
>
> The activist known as Stop Brexit Man faces prosecution after police officers attempting to shut down his regular protest near parliament seized his equipment as controversial new protest laws came into force.
>
> Steve Bray, a former coin dealer and unsuccessful Liberal Democrat parliamentary candidate, posted videos on Twitter showing officers approaching him near Parliament Square on Tuesday. His sound system was seized.

Comment: Did you read the article to which you linked? It says the names of the legislation.

Comment: Yes, it is https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police,_Crime,_Sentencing_and_Courts_Act_2022 but everything I can find is very vague and doesn't describe the terms in which amplification in protests is restricted.

Answer (score 4):

### It says in the article

> The Metropolitan police said Bray’s equipment had been seized under section 145 of the 2011 [Police Reform Social Responsibility Act](https://www.london.gov.uk/sites/default/files/police_reform_and_social_responsibility_act_2011.pdf), which gives the force power to seize items being used for prohibited activities in Parliament Square. That includes operating amplified sound equipment in the controlled area.

It even gives the correct section truly outstanding journalism.

Comment: Yes but it is a bit contradictory and confusing as that is a 2011 act, but he was supposedly there each day without problems until the *new* provisions came into effect. So it seems that possibly the 2011 act gave police the powers of seizure of prohibited  equipment while the 2022 made amplification in parliament Square prohibited. Is that accurate?

Comment: @JosephP. The police seized Bray's equipment under s145. Apparently they also informed him of their other powers including s14ZA Public Order Act 1986 "Imposing conditions on one-person protests" (inserted by s79 Police, Crime, Sentencing and Courts Act 2022, the new law), which includes clauses related to noise. The reporting has not been clear about what the police said to Bray. But Dale M's answer is correct.